# C++ vector iterator nth_element compile error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, comparator

The code below will not compile.  There is an error on the 2nd to the last line (nth_element...).  It seems to be related to the comparator.  Compiler claims "term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments".  How do I fix the compile error?

```
    struct Result {
        Result(unsigned int id, double result);
        bool cmp(const Result &a, const Result &b)  const;

        unsigned int id;
        double result;
    };


Result::Result(unsigned int id, double result) {
    this->id = id;
    this->result = result;
}

bool Result::cmp(const Result &a, const Result &b)  const {
    if(a.result < b.result) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

    //25th-percentile
    int index = (int) ((buffer.size()+1.0)/4.0 - 0.499);
    vector<Result>::iterator itrindex = buffer.begin() + index;
    nth_element(buffer.begin(), itrindex, buffer.end(), &Result::cmp);
    double twentyfifthperc = buffer[index].result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool cmp(const Result &a, const Result &b)  const;
```

should be

```
static bool cmp(const Result &a, const Result &b);
```

Comment: Would probably be helpful to add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jarod42, that fixed it.